# Uploading Images from ReactJS frontend to PHP Server

Tags: php, reactjs

I have images saved in `this.state.pictures`. Now I want to upload these to a PHP API. But `empty($_FILES['file'][0])` always returns true.

I'm using formData.

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    this.state.pictures.forEach(function(item){
        var file = item;            
        fd.append('file[]', file);
    });
```

Then uploading using

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/julo_api/user_cars/create.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
```

Comment: So what do `$_POST` and `$_FILES` actually contain on the server side?

Comment: How are you posting the data?

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/julo_api/user_cars/create.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

Comment: "But empty($_FILES['file'][0]) always returns true" — How can you tell? Your question doesn't show how you look at the result of that expression.

Comment: "I have images saved in this.state.pictures" — Define "images": What type of object is each image? Not an HTMLImgElement I hope?

Comment: picture files, allowed type is ".jpg"  or ".png" only. user can select one or more images.

Answer (score 0):

Below use the steps to make it work.

**HTML:**

```
File upload- <input type="file" name="docupload" id="file" onChange={this.uploadfile}/>
```

**Javascript upload function:**

```
 uploadfile:function()
    {
    var doc = document.getElementById("file");
    var form = doc.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", form);

//Send the formData in post

}
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.